# Spring mockMvc throws error when using ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring-mvc, testing, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I am using SpringMockMvc and in my controller I have `@ExceptionHandler`. When calling `post` request, I am getting the below error.

```
Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.xx.xxx> com.xx.xx.handleException(java.lang.Throwable,org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request]: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest@47fac1bd
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:97)
```

I am not sure why `@ExceptionHandler` cannot handle if the request is of type `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could never work, simply because `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest` is not a sub-type of `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`. Thus, it is impossible for Spring to provide an instance of `MockHttpServletRequest` for a parameter of type `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`.

You'll need to change the type of the second parameter in your `handleException()` method to `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`.